# what is the reason for "org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN minor code: 208 completed: Maybe" error in my java corba chat application

Tags: java, chat, corba

I have been trying to run a java corba chat application ref:-https://github.com/ehl/TalkCat

In that when i first run the naming service id  nameserv.bat the error pops

> org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe
>
> Namming Service activé !!
>
> IOR : null

The error leads to this line of coding

**org.omg.CORBA.Object obj = orb.resolve_initial_references(
                "NameService");**

I have tried many java corba chat application all the application ends with this error and this line all the application seams to have this same coding error what is this error how can i resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start the `tnameserver` in command prompt and then start your name server in your program.

This is the command for run tnameserve : `tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050` .

Comment: thanks radha this works fine i am able to get the ior value after starting the tnameserver....thank you very much\

Answer (score 2):

If Host Name or Port No mismatches, you may get this error. The Host Name and Port Number in the arguments of run_oss_client.bat/sh file should match with that of Java IDL Name Server.

Though no run_oss_client script in AS10G R2, You can work out easily after noticed another Report is running on the same machine. It is: **Reuse existing naming service port on the same machine.**

Please try the following.

Modify **$ORACLE_HOME/reports/conf/rwnetwork.conf** to let it use other naming service port number on the same server.

```
<discoveryService>
  <namingService name="Cos" host="127.0.0.1" port="14021"/>
</discoveryService>
```